# Android service, need a service that keeps running

Tags: android, android-service, android-debug

I am a beginner in Android development. I want to build a service that once started, must keep running.

**Step 1.)** Once user will install the app give some input, service will start. (*i'll use IntentService*)

**Step 2.)** Now user moves to other app/close my app. I want to make sure Service should keep running and processing/saving info with current timestamps.

**Questions:**

**1.)** How I make sure that the service keeps running/saving data even if user returns after say, 1 month on my app.

**2.)** I read that every app is a new user and separate VM is provided by the Android, question is when an app is considered to be closed?

**3.)** If my app closes, related services will also close then?

Comment: Fortunately, this is not practical, for the sake of the user. I would suggest that you open a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide much more detail about "keep running and processing/saving info with current timestamps", so that people can suggest ways of implementing that efficiently and effectively.

Comment: @CommonsWare: kindly look at my answer and correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
1.) How I make sure that the service keeps running/saving data even if user returns after say, 1 month on my app.
```

Once user installs app, you can start `STICKY` [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) but make sure you inform the user as well as Android OS by making it run on `foreground` with `on going notification`. it will help your service to run for long time without being killed by Android OS.

1 month is long period, user may reboot the cell in between. and you will need to restart your service. so you should register for reboot complete [event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) .

```
2.) I read that every app is a new user and separate VM is provided by the Android, question is when an app is considered to be closed?
```

There is no condition like considered to be closed.Actually, when user installs app, it is by default in `stopped` mode, it gets activated when user opens your app for first time. and application can go back to `stopped` mode again whenever user `force stop` your app.

```
3.) If my app closes, related services will also close then?
```

If you are considering that app is considered as closed when user don't use the app,your service won't close unless Android OS kills it in low memory situation.you may make it `foreground` as suggested earlier to convey Android OS that `you are doing important things,nothing is wrong,so kill me only at last when you don't have any other options left`

Comment: Thanks @Mehul !!! Can you suggest me some websites where I can find some good examples on Android Services.

Comment: @JyotiPrakash: you can find out robust implementation examples of service  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)